# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 0.)

Tags: amazon-s3

When I am uploading video frames in my app it throws an error. I copied the code here, Can anyone please help me to overcome the error?

```
let directoryURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let fileURL: URL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("test.h264")

let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,
    identityPoolId:"us-east-1:5338ad28-9e8f-4347-a150-cabb7bc96ff7")

let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
s3Url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url

let key = "test.h264"
let request = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
request.bucket = "skilai"
request.key = key
request.body = fileURL
request.acl = .publicReadWrite
request.contentType = "test/h264"

let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
transferManager.upload(request).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread()) { (task) -> Any? in
    if let error = task.error
    {
        print("AWS Upload error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if task.result != nil
    {
        print("Uploaded \(key)")
        let contentUrl = self.s3Url.appendingPathComponent("skilai").appendingPathComponent(key)
        self.contentUrl = contentUrl
    }

    return nil
}
```